# Multiple least cost paths - automated labeling of the calculated paths with formula starting-point_destination-point?

Tags: qgis, labeling, cost-path, least-cost

I am using r.cost and r.drain to calculate a least cost path, using a single friction layer (slope), in a set of points, from each single point to the other. I would like to use the same approach on a significantly bigger set of points (up to 200). Is there a way to introduce automatic labeling of the calculated least cost paths (lines) with a formula starting-point_to_stopping-point? I would want to avoid to label each single calculated line manually, it would be time - consuming and ultimatelly would deter me from the whole process.

Comment: So do you have the least cost lines in a vector layer?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but right now I don't understand what data you have.

Comment: Will try to clarify:i have a set of point data in .shp format,which represent sites of interest. Im able to calculate least cost lines as a vector layer by using r.cost and r.drain, generating paths between all the points in the set (-1) (destination points)  to a single point (starting point,part of the set). I would repeat this procedure for each point, calculating least cost lines, untill all the points in the set were at some point starting station for the least cost line. These lines need to be labeled, in a way that starting and destination point is included in the label field.

Answer (score 1):

To label a line with its starting and ending coordinates, put this expression in the 'Label with' text box:

[image]

```
concat($x_at(0), ',', $y_at(0), ' to ', $x_at(-1), ',', $y_at(-1))
```

The label will look like this:

[image]

Other combinations are possible, depending on how you want the label formatted. The basic idea is to assemble the different parts of the label inside the `concat()` function.

Tips:

- If the coordinates don't display properly, you may need to force QGIS to interpret them as text instead of numbers by wrapping them in the `to_string()` function, like this:

  ```
  concat(to_string($x_at(0)), ',', to_string($y_at(0)), ' to ', to_string($x_at(-1)), ',', to_string($y_at(-1)))
  ```
- Use the `round()` function to shorten a long decimal number
- To add a line break, include `'\n'` in the label.